# How to enforce the appearance of a Tab in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to configure a Salesforce application that requires the Case standard object. I have:

- Edited the profiles that need to see this object so that they have object permissions to read the Case object.
- Set Tab Visibility to *Default On*
- Ensured that the Case object has been included in the application.

My issue is that when I log in as one of the target users, I still can't see the Cases tab. The users could just configure their tab layout via the `Customize Tab Layout` button, but I would like to enforce the appearance of the Cases tab as it is essential to the application.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: When you logged in as the user, did you change their application to your newly created one?

Comment: @Tezyn - Thanks for your comment. Yes they are on the correct app.

Comment: Is it a standard tab or custom tab with a visualforce page included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the settings of your App (Setup - Create - App - Edit Your app):

- App: Selected Tabs -> your tab is there
- App: Assign to Profiles -> target user profile is there

Check the settings of the target user profile:

- Tab Settings: Cases -> Default On
- Standard Object Permissions: Cases -> Read
- Custom App Settings: your app -> Visible